# Symfony - ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php

Tags: php, symfony

while putting my app in production, i had to FTP-transfer the JMS Serializer as i can't use composer on the production server.

It worked, i see it in the vendor.

My AppKernel is the same as in local (where it works, as tested in both production and dev environment) :

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
        new FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle(),
        new Hager\TransformationBundle\TransformationBundle(),
        new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle()
    );

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}

public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
}
```

but i recieve a very strange

> ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 22:
>   Attempted to load class "JMSSerializerBundle" from namespace "JMS\SerializerBundle".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

As the console isn't available on production server either, i did `rm -RF /app/cache/*` but still got the error.

Help very wlecome.

Comment: Looks like class loader is not loading JMSSerializer classes. Did you update composer.json and composer.lock files in production or you just uploaded jms serializer to vendor folder?

Comment: he said he cannot use composer in production server

Comment: i cant use composer in production so yes, i just ftp-uploaded it in the vendor folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also upload the `vendor/composer` directory again.

and upload your `web` directory too since there might be new assets.

Then go to `app/cache` and delete everything inside.

**Another approach:**

download and install the [CoreSphere ConsoleBundle](https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle)

add your ip address in app_dev.php:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1', '100.200.300.400')) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
)
```

(replace 100.200.300.400 for your own ip) and upload this file to the server . Then visit your website in **app_dev.php/_console** and you can execute your console commands from there.

Answer (score 1):

You said you cannot run Composer in your prod server (why?!). In that case, even if you copy your JMS Serializer files to the vendor dir, they will not be autoloaded by the autoloader that composer generates. You will need to edit the `autoload_namespaces.php` file in your `vendor/composer` dir and add this line:

```
'JMS\\SerializerBundle' => array ($vendorDir . '/jms/serializer-bundle'),
```

Answer (score 0):

DO not rename or replace Comoser.lock andcomposer.json files.
Installnew project `symfony new project` and replace folders from broken project to new one : app,src,web.